# How an application can start its own service after it closes in Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, service

I have an application that the user can start in two different ways, as a normal application or as a Windows service. When the service is already running (there's a icon of it in the system tray) and the user tries to start the application (not just open by clicking on the tray icon, but start again clicking in Start>Applications>Blah blah), it says: "*The application is already running as a Service, do you want to close the service and start the App?*" When the user clicks 'Yes' the application closes the service and starts itself as a normal application.

When that occurs I put a flag indicating that the user had once stopped the service and when they close the application the software sees the flag and the service has to start running again, because it was closed before to start as a normal app.

I tried to put:

```
WinExec(PChar('NET START MyApplicationName'),SW_shownormal);
```

in the `OnClose` event, before this line:

```
ExitProcess(0);
```

but it says that the service is already running and closes the application without starting the service, and if I put it after that line it doesn't do anything at all.
Is there any way to do this?

When I put the line before the `ExitProcess(0);` it opens a cmd window with the message:

> "The service is not responding to the control function"

then it closes the application, closes the cmd window and it doesn't start the service.

Comment: You start a service by calling `StartService`. But standard users can't start and stop services. Your design is going to force the app to run as admin, or spawn a separate elevated process to start the service, and incur a UAC dialog. It would make more sense, to me, to keep the service running all the time and let it do the work with the standard app acting as a front end.

Comment: I don't find it surprising that it doesn't do nothing at all after a call to `ExitProcess`.

Comment: `ExitProcess(0)` is basically killing the application, nothing else can possibly happen after that.

Comment: "and when he closes the application the software sees the flag and the service have to start running again" -- if an application intentionally restarts itself when I tell it to quit, I start looking for the uninstaller.

Comment: @hvd if the application start as a service and the user closes in service mode the app ends. If starts as a service, then the user open as a normal app the service stops and the normal app open, then when the user closes it the app ends and the service start running again. Because if the app starts as a service it have to keep running until the user closes the app in service mode, not in "normal mode".

Comment: @user1410363 I get that, but speaking as a user (perhaps an atypical user, but a user nonetheless), I'm not going to see that. I'm seeing the process once in the task manager before quitting, quit it, and see it respawn as a new process in the task manager.

Comment: If you're really going to notice that, @Hvd, then you'll also notice that the same sequence happened when you *started* the application. When you started it, the service version of the program stopped.

Comment: @RobKennedy I really do notice, when I'm already looking in the task manager looking to see what's running what shouldn't be, and trying to quit those applications nicely. That doesn't apply when starting the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a simple Batch file like that

```
@ECHO OFF
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 > NUL
NET START MyApplicationName
```

Then run execute this batch file before close your program.

```
ShellExecute(0, 'Open', YourBatchFile, nil, nil, SW_HIDE)
```

Comment: Ping will immediately return an error if there's no network connection, unless you're not pinging localhost. Workaround: `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 > NUL`, but then that's an implementation detail that successive pings wait 1 sec.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! (David Heffernan's answer was great too but I'm working in another person project, a big project so I cannot make huge changes on it, and I don't have the time to do it, but thanks too David!).

Answer (score 7):

In my view you are over-complicating the problem. Starting and stopping services is a complicated action and indeed it is forbidden by default for non-admin users. This very fact will make your application very annoying to use. You will limit its use to admin users, and also pepper them with UAC dialogs. Nobody likes apps like that.

The alternative is to simply leave your service running the whole time, but make it inactive whilst the standard desktop app is running. When the desktop app starts it strikes up communication with the service using some form of IPC and asks the service to stop work. The service does this and then the desktop app proceeds. When the desktop app closes, the service is asked to resume work. You would want to keep a communication channel open the whole time to guard against the desktop app terminating abnormally – if that happened the service would simply start up again.

Now, if you really wanted to do a good job you could let all the processing of work always happen in the service. The desktop app would merely be a front end for the service. That would seem to me to be the most efficient and logical design for this app.